# tinymce-4 - absolute positioned element won't let me edit the content

Tags: tinymce-4

I hope anybody has experience with TinyMCE here - their forum is not very helpful... ;)

I have an absolute positioned element (div, table, doesn't matter) with some text in it.

When I click onto the text to edit it, it just selects the element and adds the positioning-tool (the little plus-sign) to it. It won't let me edit the content, though.

In order to edit the content, I have to click outside the element and then use the keyboard (cursor) to move the caret to the text I want to edit. Not very comfortable...

Any ideas why this is happening?

[Edit]

Meanwhile, I found out it's working in Safari - but not in Firefox (current Version 23.x)

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: As I stated, this was (is) a FireFox related issue. I just use Chrome or Safari now.